# como recorrer atributos de una clase en C#?

Tags: c#, algoritmos

tengo varias clases con atributos distintos, uno de ellos por ejemplo es:

```
class MGestion
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public String gestion { get; set; }
    public String inicio { get; set; }
    public String fin { get; set; }
    public String descripcion { get; set; }
    public MGestion(int a,String g,String i,String f,String d) {
        age = a;
        gestion = g;
        inicio = i;
        fin = f;
        descripcion = d;
    }
}
```

Lo que deseo hacer es poder recorrer estos **atributos** como se los hace con una `array` y **obtener el nombre y tipo de dato** de cada uno de ellos.

Es decir algo asi:

> **nombre:** age, **tipo de dato**: int
>   **nombre:** gestion, **tipo de dato**: String
>   .. y asi con todos

No se si fuera posible. Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿Por atributos te refieres a las declaraciones puestas por encima de las variables? Como: `[Serializable] public class X { ... }` O ¿Sólo quieres recorrer los campos que tiene tu clase para obtener el nombre y el tipo?

Comment: Reflection es lo que estas buscando, si lo que queres es sacar los datos...

Comment: @NaCl, la verdad no te entiendo lo de `[Serializable] public class X { ... }`, y si solo quisiera sacar los campos de mi clase.

Comment: Lo de `[Serializable]` es un ejemplo de un atributo de clase, campo o lo que fuera, quería saber que era exactamente lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para obtener los nombres y los tipos de cada campo en tu clase, solo necesitas utilizar el operador `typeof` y una que otra cosilla.

Los ejemplos que pondré ahora, hacen uso de la clase `System.Console` para mostrar resultados en pantalla.

`System.Type` solo almacena información sobre el tipo al que pertenece, es decir, su propia clase.

#### Método 1: Obtener nombres y tipos de los campos en una clase.

Ahora bien, asumimos con la clase que nos has puesto en el ejemplo, le he hecho algunas modificaciones para que se pueda hacer lo que necesitas de la manera simple de entender:

```
public class MGestion
{
    public int age;
    public String gestion;
    public String inicio;
    public String fin;
    public String descripcion;
}
```

Dentro de la función que quieres utilizar para imprimir los miembros, solo necesitas hacer lo siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

// Namespace, class Program, class MGestion, etc...
public static void Main()
{
    Type Datos = typeof (MGestion);
    Console.WriteLine("Los campos de la clase '" + Datos.Name + "', son:");
    foreach (FieldInfo F 
         in Datos.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)) // Aqui ocurre la magia :)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre: '{0,-12}', Tipo: '{1,-10}'", F.Name, F.FieldType.Name);
    }
}
```

Esto va a buscar todos los campos `public`, `private` y que no sean `static` debido a los `BindingFlags` que he puesto dentro de la función.

El código arriba va a arrojar algo como:

```
Los campos de la clase 'MGestion', son:
Nombre: 'age         ', Tipo: 'Int32     '
Nombre: 'gestion     ', Tipo: 'String    '
Nombre: 'inicio      ', Tipo: 'String    '
Nombre: 'fin         ', Tipo: 'String    '
Nombre: 'descripcion ', Tipo: 'String    '
```

#### Método 2: Obtener nombres y tipo de las propiedades en una clase.

Como bien sabemos, los campos y las propiedades son dos cosas distintas, misteriosamente, las propiedades tambien son variables, pero más bonitas y eso.

Para obtener la lista de propiedades e imprimir su valor, simplemente tenemos que cambiar dos cosas a la forma que utilizamos más arriba para que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo F 
     in Datos.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)) // Aqui ocurre la magia :)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Nombre: '{0,-12}', Tipo: '{1,-10}'", F.Name, F.PropertyType);
}
```

En este método sólo buscamos las propiedades de la clase, sean `public`o `private` y que no sean `static`, probado con la siguiente clase:

```
public class MGestion
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public String gestion { get; set; } 
    public String inicio { get; set; } 
    public String fin { get; set; } 
    public String descripcion { get; set; } 
    private int x { get; set; } 
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public string c;
}
```

Muestra algo como lo siguiente en pantalla:

```
Los campos de la clase 'MGestion', son:
Nombre: 'a           ', Tipo: 'Int32     '
Nombre: 'b           ', Tipo: 'Int32     '
Nombre: 'c           ', Tipo: 'String    '

Las propiedades de la clase 'MGestion' son:
Nombre: 'age         ', Tipo: 'System.Int32'
Nombre: 'gestion     ', Tipo: 'System.String'
Nombre: 'inicio      ', Tipo: 'System.String'
Nombre: 'fin         ', Tipo: 'System.String'
Nombre: 'descripcion ', Tipo: 'System.String'
Nombre: 'x           ', Tipo: 'System.Int32'
```

Espero te haya ayudado, [aquí](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LEPNzu) te dejo un fiddle para que veas como funciona :D

Comment: Muchas gracias @NaCI, me salvaste el dia.